# how to send search request in xmlrpc(openerp) android

Tags: android

I am writing the code for calling the search function like this:

```
Object[] paramsObj = new Object[1];
paramsObj[0] = new Object[] {"surveyor", "=", s.mUserId};
Long[] ids = s.search("atm.surverys.management", paramsObj);
```

but I am getting an error like this:

```
01-23 08:10:18.422: W/System.err(2845): java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize null
01-23 08:10:18.432: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:99)
01-23 08:10:18.432: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCSerializer.serialize(XMLRPCSerializer.java:61)
01-23 08:10:18.442: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCCommon.serializeParams(XMLRPCCommon.java:36)
01-23 08:10:18.452: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.methodCall(XMLRPCClient.java:250)
01-23 08:10:18.452: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.callEx(XMLRPCClient.java:170)
01-23 08:10:18.462: W/System.err(2845):     at org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCClient.call(XMLRPCClient.java:281)
01-23 08:10:18.472: W/System.err(2845):     at com.example.transtech1.OpenErpConnect.search(OpenErpConnect.java:180)
01-23 08:10:18.483: W/System.err(2845):     at com.example.transtech1.OpenErpConnect.search(OpenErpConnect.java:143)
01-23 08:10:18.483: W/System.err(2845):     at com.example.transtech1.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:64)
01-23 08:10:18.502: W/System.err(2845):     at com.example.transtech1.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-23 08:10:18.502: W/System.err(2845):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-23 08:10:18.512: W/System.err(2845):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-23 08:10:18.522: W/System.err(2845):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-23 08:10:18.522: W/System.err(2845):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-23 08:10:18.543: W/System.err(2845):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-23 08:10:18.543: W/System.err(2845):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-23 08:10:18.552: D/OpenErpConnect(2845): org.xmlrpc.android.XMLRPCException: java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize null
```

Comment: but i was done login like this

Comment: Object[]  params1= new Object[2];
params1[0]= new String(userName);
params1[1]=new String(userPassword);
OpenErpConnect oc = OpenErpConnect.connect("192.168.1.11", 8069, "Transtech", "admin", "admin");
OpenErpConnect s = oc.login("192.168.1.11", 8069, "Transtech", userName, userPassword);

Comment: any one can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The connector which you are using was apparently designed for OpenERP 6.0
If you are using a more recent version of OpenERP then you should look at the newsearch method written by zahidj in response to [Issue #4 in the android-openerp GitHub repository](https://github.com/zikzakmedia/android-openerp/issues/4).

The "Cannot serialize null" error is not raised when the newsearch method is called instead of the search method to connect to OpenERP 7.0 and Odoo 8.0 servers.